# How to delete a old image when it is updated?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want the previous picture uploaded by the user to be deleted when the user updates it.

I have tried modifying `form_valid` of the UserUpdate view and also in the `save` method of the form (Not sure where I should make this)

This way:

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        old_image = self.instance.picture.path
        os.remove(old_image)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I get an error saying `'ImageFileDescriptor' object has no attribute 'path'`.
Couldn't find anything useful about ImageFileDescriptor.

But if I do it in the form like this:

```
def save(self):
    old_image = self.instance.picture.path
    os.remove(old_image)
```

The picture I get is the one I'm about to upload in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I use [django-cleanup](https://github.com/un1t/django-cleanup) in my project and it works very well.

So you do the following:

`pip install django-cleanup`

And then in your `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
     ...
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig', # should go at the end
)
```

Remember to put it last.